# Не поддерживается SQL Server в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2019

Всем здравия, я хочу подсоединить базу данных SQL Server в Visual Studio, но при попытке соединения получаю сообщение: "обнаружено, что отсутствуют компоненты, обеспечивающие поддержку SQL Server", как на фото. Подскажите, что делать? У меня есть "Хранение и обработка данных" в рабочих нагрузках VS.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовали нажимать на кнопку "ОК"? Вдруг там действительно нет некоторых требуемых пакетов, которые можно установить через эту кнопку?

Comment: Откройте установщик Visual Studio и установите SQL Server Data Tools

Comment: Я решил проблему, просто установил VS 2022 вместо VS 2019)